# HTTP authentication in Groovy?

Tags: authentication, groovy, httpbuilder

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(url)
http.auth.basic username, password

def data = new URL(url)

def response = data.getText()

def relativePaths = new XmlParser().parseText(response)

relativePaths.each {page ->

    def link = page.content.@href.first()

    if(link.contains(".txt")){
        println link
    }

}
```

Hi,

when trying to run this, I get a 401. It seems like here:

```
def response = data.getText()
```

it is actually not authenticated anymore (or at all) ? In Ruby I would write it like that:

```
(open(url, :http_basic_authentication => [username, password])
data = Nokogiri::XML(open(url, :http_basic_authentication => [username, password])))
```

How would that look like in Groovy ? Am I using `httpbuilder` wrong ? Thanks a lot in advance !

**Update 1:**

After applying the changes:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(url)
http.auth.basic username, password

http.get(path: url, contentType: ContentType.TEXT) { resp, reader ->

    def relativePaths = new XmlParser().parse(reader)

    relativePaths.each { page ->

        def link = page.content.@href.first()

        if (link.contains(".txt")) {
            println link
        }
    }
}
```

I get an 406:

Response code: 406; found handler: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure@5be46f9d
Caught: groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Not Acceptable
groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Not Acceptable

**Update 2:**

Still not working. I changed the contentType to XML and the path to the actual path, but getting an error message:

```
GET <URL>/<PATH>:(id:ContinuousIntegration_BuildTestDistribute)/artifacts/children/
Response code: 200; found handler: ArtifactDownloader$_run_closure1@5be46f9d
Parsing response as: application/xml
Could not find charset in response; using UTF-8
Parsed data to instance of: class groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.XmlParser.parse() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild) values: []
Possible solutions: parse(java.io.File), parse(java.io.InputStream), parse(java.io.Reader), parse(java.lang.String), parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.XmlParser.parse() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild) values: []
Possible solutions: parse(java.io.File), parse(java.io.InputStream), parse(java.io.Reader), parse(java.lang.String), parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)
    at ArtifactDownloader$_run_closure1.doCall(ArtifactDownloader.groovy:14)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$1.handleResponse(HTTPBuilder.java:503)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:218)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:160)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:515)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.get(HTTPBuilder.java:285)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$get.call(Unknown Source)
    at ArtifactDownloader.run(ArtifactDownloader.groovy:12)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Just for comparison, the Ruby script. Maybe `httpbuilder` is just not what I want ? I actually wanted to use it for authentication only.

```
(open(url, :http_basic_authentication => [username, password])
data = Nokogiri::XML(open(url, :http_basic_authentication => [username, password])))

relativePaths = data.xpath("//content/@href")

relativePaths.each { |path| 
    if path.text.include? ".apk"
        puts "<URL>:<PORT>"+path.text
    end
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Are you ready for a face palm?

You created an `HTTPBuilder` and... never used it. You got it all set up...

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(url)
http.auth.basic(username, password)
```

... but then used a new `URL` to retrieve the data:

```
def data = new URL(url)
def response = data.getText()
```

### Solution

An [HTTPBuilder](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/blob/master/src/main/java/groovyx/net/http/HTTPBuilder.java) is used like this:

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.ContentType

http.get(path : path, contentType : ContentType.TEXT) { resp, reader ->
    def relativePaths = new XmlParser().parse(reader)    
    ...
}
```

Note: I'm not sure whether the `get()` method runs in the background or not.

### Updated solution

Setting the content type to XML instructs `HTTPBuilder` to parse the response and provide the parsed document as the second argument. The document is represented as a [Node](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Node.html).

```
http.get(path : path, contentType : ContentType.XML) { response, node ->
    def relativePaths = node    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Face palm, indeed. Now I'm getting a 406. Maybe I'm just tired ;-)

Comment: The content type may be wrong. It's probably supposed to be ContentType.XML. It's my turn to face palm!

Comment: Oh, the url given to `http.get()` is actually supposed to be a path relative to the url given to `HTTPBuilder`. For example, the url might be *http://www.google.com* and the path */search*.

Comment: Thanks! I changed those things, but it still doesn't seem to work. I posted the Ruby code above, just realized I used xpath there.

Comment: The problem is no longer with HTTPBuilder. It's authenticating and providing the response. The stack trace provided a clue: *Parsed data to instance of: class groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.XmlParser.parse() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild)*. It turns out that HTTPBuilder takes the content type into account when providing the response. In this case, it's parsing the XML document on your behalf :) So *stream* is really a *Node*. I updated my answer to demonstrate this.